# PureFtpD to Proftp Password Conversion

Tags: linux, encryption, proftpd, hash, pureftpd

I am planning to migrate users from pureftp to proftpd, i need a tool to perform password conversion

Mysql password format-
MYSQLCrypt      md5

pureftp From:
9dd4e461268c8034f5c8564e155c67a6

Proftpd - To
$1$64eb18f6a8f793689ad1eb1136f43ccf

Answer (score 0):

Converting one hash to another is impossible by definition.

All you can do is using old hash as is if it supported by Proftpd.

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sql_passwd.html
https://infosecscout.com/convert-md5-to-sha256/